# Как на LaTeXе Настроить выравнивание в каждой ячейке или столбце отдельно?

Tags: таблицы, latex

Есть таблица простенькая, разделенная на две (не знаю насколько это правильно). Как из неё сделать то, что на прикрепленном скрине? Конкретно чтобы не было нумерации таблицы, и чтобы в каждом столбце было свое выравнивание строки.
[image: То, что нужно сделать]

```latex
\begin{table}
\caption*{Приоритеты арифметических операций в bash}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{p{2.5cm} p{3.2cm} p{7cm}}
\hline
Приоритет & Операция & Значение \\
1 & 2 & 3 \\\hline
1 & VAR ++, VAR -- & пост-инкремент/декремент \\
2 & ++ VAR, -- VAR & пре-инкремент/декремент \\
3 & +, - & унарный плюс/минус \\ 
4 & !, ˜ & логическое/побитовое отрицание \\
5 & ** & возведение в степень\\
6 & *, /, \% & умножение/деление/остаток\\
7 & +, - & сложение/вычитание\\
8 & <<, >> & левый/правый побитовый сдвиг\\
9 & <=, >=, <, > & сравнение\\
\hline
\multicolumn{3}{c}{см. далее}\\\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\begin{table}
\caption*{Приоритеты арифметических операций в bash (продолжение)}
\begin{tabular}{p{2.5cm} p{3.2cm} p{7cm}}
\hline
11 & \& & побитовая конъюнкция \\\hline
12 & ˆ & побитовое исключающее «или» \\
13 & | & побитовая дизъюнкция \\
14 & \&\& & логическая конъюнкция \\ 
15 & выражение ? выражение : выражение & условное вычисление \\
16 & =, *=, /=, \%=, +=, -=, <<=, >>=, \&=, ˆ=,|= & присваивания\\
17 & , & разделитель между выражениями\\
18 & || & логическая дизъюнкция\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

И вот, что я пока имею:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: С выравниванием текста в отдельных ячейках разобрался, сделал с помощью \multicolumn, а вот с нумерацией и переносом таблицы не разобрался

Comment: Если я правильно понял проблему, вместо окружения `tabular` используйте `longtable` или `supertabular` из одноименных пакетов - они умеют переносить таблицы на другую страницу и полуавтоматически (надо попросить) переносить на новые страницы заголовки столбцов. `longtable` мне удобнее в использовании, и может, чуть больше умеет. Если Вы хотели вообще убрать нумерацию, то не используйте `\caption{}` (да и окружение `table` тогда не сильно надо), а разместите заголовки ручками.

Comment: Для переноса таблицы можно использовать пакет ```xltabular``` - он умеет переносить таблицы и выравнивать столбцы по ширине листа. Для заголовков можно использовать пакет ```caption``` - там широкие возможности для редактирования заголовков плавающих объектов. Как убрать нумерацию - пока не выяснил, но это реально. Попробую чуть позже развёрнутое решение дать, если никто это не сделает до меня =)

Comment: Спасибо большое, вроде разобрался

Answer (score 0):

Вот, что у меня получилось:

```
\documentclass[fontsize=14bp,a4paper]{scrreprt}

% Подключение пакетов
%===================================================
\usepackage{polyglossia}    %для русского языка
\usepackage{caption} %заголовки плавающих объектов <==ЭТО ВАЖНО!
\usepackage{xltabular} %таблицы на несколько листов <==ЭТО ВАЖНО!

% Установка параметров для документа
%===================================================
\setdefaultlanguage{russian}  % устанавливает главный язык документа, опция - убирает последнюю точку в нумерации заголовков
\setotherlanguage{english} % объявляет второй язык документа
\pagestyle{plain} %номера страниц будут печататься снизу и при этом колонтитулов не будет
\setmainfont{Liberation Serif}
\setsansfont{Liberation Serif}
\setmonofont{Liberation Mono}

%параметры картинок и таблиц <==ЭТО ВАЖНО!
\captionsetup[table]{font=small, justification=centering, singlelinecheck=false} %установки для таблиц

%счётчики для автоматической нумерации строк таблицы <==НЕ ОСОБО ВАЖНО, НО ПРОСТО ПРИЯТНЫЙ БОНУС =)
\newcounter{rowno}
\setcounter{rowno}{0}

\begin{document}
    %следующий текст - заглушка, чтобы таблица переехала на следующую страницу
    Повседневная практика показывает, что выбранный нами инновационный путь в значительной степени обуславливает создание существующих финансовых и административных условий! Задача организации, в особенности же социально-экономическое развитие в значительной степени обуславливает создание направлений прогрессивного развития. С другой стороны постоянное информационно-техническое обеспечение нашей деятельности представляет собой интересный эксперимент проверки системы масштабного изменения ряда параметров.
    
    Равным образом рамки и место обучения кадров позволяет оценить значение позиций, занимаемых участниками в отношении поставленных задач. Практический опыт показывает, что реализация намеченного плана развития обеспечивает актуальность позиций, занимаемых участниками в отношении поставленных задач. Разнообразный и богатый опыт консультация с профессионалами из IT играет важную роль в формировании модели развития? Соображения высшего порядка, а также сложившаяся структура организации играет важную роль в формировании позиций, занимаемых участниками в отношении поставленных задач.
    
    С другой стороны курс на социально-ориентированный национальный проект в значительной степени обуславливает создание системы обучения кадров, соответствующей насущным потребностям. Значимость этих проблем настолько очевидна, что дальнейшее развитие различных форм деятельности позволяет выполнить важнейшие задания по разработке форм воздействия. С другой стороны дальнейшее развитие различных форм деятельности влечет за собой процесс внедрения и модернизации новых предложений. Дорогие друзья, консультация с профессионалами из IT способствует повышению актуальности позиций, занимаемых участниками в отношении поставленных задач?
    
    Разнообразный и богатый опыт новая модель организационной...
    
    \begin{xltabular}{\linewidth}{>{\small\centering\arraybackslash\stepcounter{rowno}\therowno}r>{\small\raggedright\arraybackslash}X>{\small\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
        \caption*{Приоритеты арифметических операций в bash} \\
        
        \hline
        \multicolumn{1}{>{\small}c}{Приоритет} &
        \multicolumn{1}{>{\small}l}{Операция} & \multicolumn{1}{>{\small}l}{Значение} \\
        \multicolumn{1}{>{\small\centering\arraybackslash}c}{1} &
        \multicolumn{1}{>{\small\centering\arraybackslash}c}{2} & \multicolumn{1}{>{\small\centering\arraybackslash}c}{3} \\
        \hline
        \endfirsthead
        
        \multicolumn{3}{>{\small}c}{Приоритеты арифметических операций в bash (продолжение)} \\
        \hline
        \multicolumn{1}{>{\small\centering\arraybackslash}m{2.5cm}}{1} &
        \multicolumn{1}{>{\small}c}{2} & \multicolumn{1}{>{\small}c}{3} \\ \hline
        \endhead
        
        \hline
        \multicolumn{3}{>{\small}c}{см. далее} \\
        \hline
        \endfoot
        
        \hline
        \endlastfoot
        
        & VAR ++, VAR -- & пост-инкремент/декремент \\
        & ++ VAR, -- VAR & пре-инкремент/декремент \\
        & +, - & унарный плюс/минус \\ 
        & !, ˜ & логическое/побитовое отрицание \\
        & ** & возведение в степень\\
        & *, /, \% & умножение/деление/остаток\\
        & +, - & сложение/вычитание\\
        & <<, >> & левый/правый побитовый сдвиг\\
        & <=, >=, <, > & сравнение \\
        & \& & побитовая конъюнкция \\
        & ˆ & побитовое исключающее «или» \\
        & | & побитовая дизъюнкция \\
        & \&\& & логическая конъюнкция \\ 
        & выражение ? выражение : выражение & условное вычисление \\
        & =, *=, /=, \%=, +=, -=, <<=, >>=, \&=, ˆ=,|= & присваивания\\
        & , & разделитель между выражениями\\
        & || & логическая дизъюнкция
        \\
    \end{xltabular}

\end{document}
```

Результат выглядит следующим образом:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Возможно где-то неправильно сделал выравнивание или начертание шрифта, но это уже доработаете сами.

Comment: Спасибо, очень помогло! Но ещё возник такой вопрос: можно ли как-то заставить конкретную таблицу появляться на конкретной странице, чтобы и перенос сработал? У меня просто несколько таблиц сразу и xtabular вместо того чтобы вставить таблицу к другим на страницу и используя перенос, сразу вставляется в следующую страницу, и на предыдущей остается пустое место.

Comment: ```xtabular``` не умеет разбивать таблицу на страницы, если я правильно помню. Поэтому переносит её на следующую. Попробуйте ```xltabular```, который я в примере использовал.

Comment: ну вот в моем случае с использованием вашего кода он не переносит её, а просто вставляет на следующую страницу целиком

Comment: Всё, получилось. Мешали \begin{table} и \end{table}